# Replacement for Spin Control.app

Tags: xcode, macos, debugging, freeze

Since Apple have dropped Spin Control.app—the unresponsive state process monitoring and logging utility—I am in need of a replacement.

I know I can use `spindump` directly, but I really liked the automated graphical front-end for it.

Can anyone suggest a good replacement?

My needs are: automatically sample my process by name and store the log when the process becomes unresponsive.

Answer (score 5):

I've been desperately looking for a spin control alternative, and I noticed within Intruments there's a tool called "spin monitor". Annoyingly, this isn't shown within the initial template wizard, you have to find it by clicking library in the titlebar first (see screenshot):

[image: spin control seems to now be spin monitor within instruments (xcode 4.5 on mountain lion)]

Comment: This is close to what I want. But it is quite cumbersome to use in the huge interface of Instruments.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not particularly experienced with development in XCode so this answer might not be what you are looking for, but after a while searching and reading up on Spin Control.app I found [this article](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/PerformanceOverview/InitialEvaluation/InitialEvaluation.html) in the Apple Developer documentation.

It appears that there is no single tool that replaces Spin Control.app. Instead, Apple wish for you to now use a combination of [Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652), their unified collection of utilities for debugging and monitoring iOS/OSX apps, and [Shark](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/PerformanceOverview/InitialEvaluation/InitialEvaluation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001410-CH206-SW8), an advanced tool for sampling/tracing a single application or all running applications.

In particular, you may find this feature of Shark to be useful:

> Shark also offers the windowed time facility feature for several of
>   its sampling options. The windowed time facility tells Shark to record
>   and process a finite buffer of the most recently acquired samples.
>   This feature lets Shark record data continuously and for long periods
>   of time in the background. You can then direct Shark to stop sampling
>   only after something interesting occurs in your code

Comment: The advantage of Spin Control is that it _automatically_ identifies beachball situations and takes a sample. Shark doesn't seem to be included in the latest Xcode 4.

Comment: For me with Mountain Lion: Shark will not launch. If I understand correctly the Wikipedia page for Apple Developer Tools, [Shark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Developer_Tools#Shark) was probably deprecated around the time of release of Lion.

Answer (score 0):

## A guess

Whilst Spin Control.app is no longer present, the operating system *might* respect changes to preferences in the `com.apple.spincontrol` domain.

*If* that is true, then a change to the value for `hangDelay` could effectively change the delay before sampling begins:

```
sh-3.2$ defaults read com.apple.spincontrol
{
    hangDelay = 5;
    watchOnlyApplication = 0;
}
sh-3.2$ defaults write com.apple.spincontrol hangDelay 10
sh-3.2$ defaults read com.apple.spincontrol
{
    hangDelay = 10;
    watchOnlyApplication = 0;
}
sh-3.2$
```

### Less likely

For when a single application was watched, I guess that the value for `watchOnlyApplication` could be either the name or PID of the process (thanks to @Aeyoun for a comment). There's a description of the feature but not the values in a 2006 MacTech article, [OS X Investigation and Troubleshooting - Part 2: The Secrets to OS X success](http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.22/22.06/2206OSXInvestigation/index.html).

I doubt that setting `watchOnlyApplication` to anything other than `0` can have any use on a system that is without Spin Control.app.

Comment: `watchOnlyApplication` would probably be the function where logs where only recorded if the unresponsive app matched that name.

Answer (score 0):

You can see all the spin dumps within `Console.app` under the section `Spin Reports`

You may use `Activity Monitor` to manually run spin control:

- Klick on the process you'd like to observe
- Use Menu View > Sample Process
- Use Menu View > Run Spindump

As of macos 12.